# Facing vulnerability security issue for dot-prop when updating to latest npm package

Tags: npm

I am trying to update npm version to latest `6.14.7` in *package.json*.

After updating npm to the latest, I ran `npm audit` and got two vulnerabilities for the `dot-prop` package dependency which is showing under npm path.

So, I tried updating the latest `dot-prop` `^5.1.1`. But still getting the same error.

Please help me with this how can I manually review and fix.

**Audit Report:**

> ```
> [root@redhatdev client]# npm audit
>
>                       === npm audit security report ===
>
>                                 Manual Review
>             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve
>
>          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
>
>
> High              Prototype Pollution
>
> Package           dot-prop
>
> Patched in        >=5.1.1
>
> Dependency of     npm [dev]
>
> Path              npm   libnpx   update-notofoer   configstore   dot-prop
>
> More info         https://npmjs.com/advisories/1213
>
>
> High              Prototype Pollution
>
> Package           dot-prop
>
> Patched in        >=5.1.1
>
> Dependency of     npm [dev]
>
> Path              npm    update-notofoer   configstore   dot-prop
>
> More info         https://npmjs.com/advisories/1213
>
>
> found 2 high severity vulnerabilities in 1674 scanned packages
>  2 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
> [root@redhatdev client]#
> ```

**Full Audit report: `npm audit --json`**

```json
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "action": "review",
      "module": "dot-prop",
      "resolves": [
        {
          "id": 1213,
          "path": "npm>libnpx>update-notifier>configstore>dot-prop",
          "dev": true,
          "optional": false,
          "bundled": true
        },
        {
          "id": 1213,
          "path": "npm>update-notifier>configstore>dot-prop",
          "dev": true,
          "optional": false,
          "bundled": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "advisories": {
    "1213": {
      "findings": [
        {
          "version": "4.2.0",
          "paths": [
            "npm>libnpx>update-notifier>configstore>dot-prop",
            "npm>update-notifier>configstore>dot-prop"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "id": 1213,
      "created": "2019-10-14T17:43:55.291Z",
      "updated": "2020-07-29T20:58:02.206Z",
      "deleted": null,
      "title": "Prototype Pollution",
      "found_by": {
        "link": "",
        "name": "Unknown",
        "email": ""
      },
      "reported_by": {
        "link": "",
        "name": "Unknown",
        "email": ""
      },
      "module_name": "dot-prop",
      "cves": [
        "CVE-2020-8116"
      ],
      "vulnerable_versions": "<5.1.1",
      "patched_versions": ">=5.1.1",
      "overview": "Versions of `dot-prop` before 5.1.1 are vulnerable to prototype pollution. The function `set` does not restrict the modification of an Object's prototype, which may allow an attacker to add or modify an existing property that will exist on all objects.\n\n",
      "recommendation": "Upgrade to version 5.1.1 or later.",
      "references": "- [GitHub advisory](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ff7x-qrg7-qggm)\n- [CVE](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-8116)",
      "access": "public",
      "severity": "high",
      "cwe": "CWE-471",
      "metadata": {
        "module_type": "",
        "exploitability": 4,
        "affected_components": ""
      },
      "url": "https://npmjs.com/advisories/1213"
    }
  },
  "muted": [],
  "metadata": {
    "vulnerabilities": {
      "info": 0,
      "low": 0,
      "moderate": 0,
      "high": 2,
      "critical": 0
    },
    "dependencies": 61,
    "devDependencies": 1612,
    "optionalDependencies": 31,
    "totalDependencies": 1674
  },
  "runId": "9b99170c-35c0-44b1-a0e6-8b714069a255"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried 'seeing the full report for details'?

Comment: @underscore_d Tried seeing full report details.No luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2**:

Now I found the Problem.

You updated npm locally. (it's in your package.json)

So please run:

`npm uninstall npm --save` (uninstall locally)

then:

`npm i npm -g` (that updates npm globally and not locally)

That fixes the problem.

### Rest of this answer is obsolete and doesn't add to the solution.

**EDIT:**
It seems to be a npm problem to me.

Here is what I did:

I had npm version `6.14.6`.

I installed `dot-prop`.

No Problem.

I updated my npm to`6.14.7`.

2 vulnerabilities.

I ran `npm audit fix` which results in `fixed 0 of 2 vulnerabilities`.

I ran `npm -v` which results in `6.14.6`.

So I think it's a problem with `npm 6.14.7` (and/or a combination with this special package)

**Original Message:**

did you also try `npm audit fix` ?

Also it says **[https://go.npm.me/audit-guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities)** for additional guidance

Did you try that as well?

Comment: I have tried npm audit fix. saying 2 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated. Also checked Audit guide, no luck there as well.

Comment: yes. also my package.json contains the "npm" : "6.14.7"    {
  "name": "test-npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dot-prop": "^5.2.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.7"
  }
}

Comment: mine as well, just remove that and you're fine :-) `npm uninstall npm --save`

Comment: finally found the solution :-) it's in the edit2. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @Andre. I will uninstall npm locally. Also wanted to know, why can't we pass the npm as package dependency?

Comment: Glad I could help. It would be nice that you accept or upvote my answer then as well. 

Well you can pass it as a dependency, but then you also have to the the `PATH` Variable of your system to this project and that makes no sense. 
npm comes with node anyway and is one of the things which should stay globally.